# Cleaning up file names for RE-NAMING

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a working script that strips the "TRASH" off of a file. But it is CLUNKY, and if you want to change the "TRASH" then it is a mess. Are there any ideas as to how to clean up this code? With a List, or dictionary, maybe?

**FILE NAME TO BE CLEANED:** *2Pac - All Eyez On Me (Offical Karaoke video with LyrIcs )-_z1tdf8Gn6Y.mp4*

> ```
> import os
> os.chdir("C:/Users/Suppe/OneDrive/Documents/Kerokey")#change working directory.
> for f in os.listdir():                               #file list.
> f2 = f.lower()                                       #make lowercase to compare text.
> file_name, File_ext = (os.path.splitext(f2))         #strip file extension.
> file_name = file_name.strip()[0:-12]                 #Strip the _z1tdf8Gn6Y off.
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("karaoke") #break the name with TRASH.
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))            #put name back together.
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("official")#repeat everything over.
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("video")
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("version")
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("lyrics")
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))
> n_beg, n_mid, n_end = file_name.partition("with")
> file_name = ('{}{}'.format(n_beg, n_end))
> file_name.strip()
> print(file_name.capitalize())                        #Reformat the name.
> #HAVEN'T GOTTEN ANY FARTHER YET.
> ```

**file name OUTPUT:** *2pac - all eyez on me ()*

**Lastly I need to remove the "()" at the end, and add the file extension so I can save the file with the new name:** *2pac - all eyez on me.mp4*

Comment: Are the names of the files all a similar format to your example here? I.e. do they all have ((Offical Karaoke video with LyrIcs) then the "trash" string?

Comment: Yes and NO. Some do some don't Examples:
Let's go crazy -  Prince  - Karaoke  - Lyrics-GwpN0eaUKb4.mp4
Karaoke Beat It - Michael Jackson -pvdrN3GJFZo.mp4
So it may have one "trash word" all of them,or any variation. They all do have random strings before the extension though. [-pvdrN3GJFZo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a pretty simple solution for you:

```
var = "2pac - all eyez on me ()"
if "()" in var:
    var = var.replace(" ()", ".mp4")
print(var)
```

Comment: you don't need to check `if "()" in var:`.